# Need to calculate percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, percentage

I want to get the `weight` as a percentage of the total `weight` for each person.

Here's my data:

```
TableA

Name        |   Size    |   Weight  
------------------------------------  
Jamie       |   0.25    |   48  
Jamie       |   0.50    |   48  
Taylor      |   0.25    |   55  
Taylor      |   0.30    |   54  
Taylor      |   0.45    |   48
```

And here's the output I would like:

```
Name    |   Size        |   Percentage  |   Weight  
---------------------------------------------------------------  
Jamie   |   0.25        |   50%     |   48  
Jamie   |   0.50        |   50%     |   48  
Taylor  |   0.25        |   35.03%      |   55  
Taylor  |   0.30        |   34.39%      |   54  
Taylor  |   0.45        |   30.57%      |   48
```

Eg the total weight for Jamie is 96 (48+48), so I have to calculate his weight values as a percentage of 96 for each row.

Comment: Can you explain the percentages you get for the other weights? I can't understand how you reached those numbers.

Comment: @Mureinik if you add 55+54+48=157, than for 0.25 size (55/157)*100

Comment: Does your version of MSSQL supports `SUM() OVER()`? Otherwise use subquery or join with grouped cte.

Comment: So is that a typo then? Is the 0.45 supposed to be 0.25?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the table to a query that calculates the sum of weight:

```
select t.name, size, 100.0 * weight / total, weight
from tableA t
join (select name, sum(weight) total
      from tableA
      group by name) s on s.name = t.name
```

This syntax will work on all relational databases (that I know).

Comment: There is 1 issue in the above code, from the above table if there is 1 more entry like **Taylor    |     0.45     |        50  ** It is calculating taylor twice,
like in the output it will be like  
taylor | 0.45  |  35 | 48  
taylor | 0.45  |  25 | 50

I want taylor to how only once if the size is same

Comment: @red what value should weight and percentage weight be for duplicate sizes? Combine (add) the weights for each size? Use the lowest/highest? Do all duplicate size rows contribute to the total?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CTE` for purpose

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
   SELECT *, 100 * Weight/SUM(Weight) OVER(Partition By Name) AS Per 
   FROM TableName
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Of course this technique would still work *without* the CTE.  The [over](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause is doing the real work here ;).  Upvoted because this is, in my opinion, the more elegant solution.

Comment: What is the cte for?

Comment: There is 1 issue in the above code, from the above table if there is 1 more entry like **Taylor    |     0.45     |        50  ** It is calculating taylor twice,
like in the output it will be like  
taylor | 0.45  |  35 | 48  
taylor | 0.45  |  25 | 50

I want taylor to how only once if the size is same